# Intelligent routing methods

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, routes

I noticed that jquery.com uses /nameOfMethod as there routing convention.  Using this to my advantage to cite sources on a previous stack question I mistyped [www.jquery.com/next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) -> [www.jquery.com/nex](http://api.jquery.com/nex/)  What I found surprising is that the routing was smart enough to see the similarity in names and correctly(perhaps incorrectly) route me.  I'm super new to back end programming.  I am just finishing up my first Project in Ruby on Rails. The project has exposed me to things like associations, CRUD, MVC and just a huge array of things I've never known of.  I'm becoming more and more concious of how the web works and this is knowledgable routing is interesting me.

Using `Ruby on Rails` as an example how would one accomplish this intelligent routing?  What kind of words are can I Google to learn more about this process?  How difficult or deep down the rabbit hole of back end programming is this interaction?  Is there anything that trumps this interaction, something more cutting edge, that you could suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in `routes.rb` you'd do something like

`match '/:itemname', to items#show`

In the Items controller you'd then have

```
def show
    item = Item.where("itemname like ?", "#{params[:itemname]}%").to_sql
    redirect_to item
end
```

In essence you're

1. Mapping root_url/name_of_an_item to an action in your controller
       which
2. Forms a SQL query that takes a wildcard after itemname that
       is used to
3. Redirect the user to the route for the item in
       question.

My example probably isn't syntactically correct, but that's the logic behind it.
Head on over to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html and read the routing and query interface guides. Everything there's great, but those two in particular might be helpful to learn more about this sort of thing.